# Best books & articles for practicing jhanas

Tags: reference-request, jhana, samatha

Which are the best books and/or articles for practicing the jhanas?

Comment: Please add list of good books from the following arahants:
Mogok Sayadaw U Vimala
Sunlun Sayadaw U Kavi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [Bhante Vimalaramsi](http://www.dhammasukha.org/the-teachings.html)
- [Thanissaro Bhikkhu](http://www.dhammatalks.org/ebook_index.html)
- [Forest Dhamma](http://www.forestdhamma.org/books/english/)
- [Forest Sangha Publications](http://forestsanghapublications.org/)
- [Buddhist eLibrary](http://www.buddhistelibrary.org/)
- [Manual of Mindfulness of Breathing](http://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh431-p.html)

Comment: May I also add to this list "Mastering the Core Teachings of the Buddha" by Daniel Ingram which has some very hopeful and practical advice for the modern layman/woman trying to cultivate. Daniel is a doctor who says jhana helped a lot during med school. I interviewed Daniel and he's a real awesome compassionate guy.

Comment: @Ahmed, at the risk of going off topic, in what context dd you interview Daniel? Was it a public interview, by which I mean, is it available anywhere to listen to or read?

Comment: It was a year back and i hit record and my recorder malfunctioned. I asked him some really practical questions about "what does enlightenment feel like?" "How to get jhana in the heat of daily life?" Etc Im trying to get another interview with him.. If i do ill let you know..

Comment: @tkp I got a time slot with him and posted a [reddit](http://redd.it/2s1n3o) to collect questions for him, going to try to interview him on 23rd.

Answer (score 4):

I have this book by Ajahn Brahm (Mindfulness, Bliss and Beyond) which has probably the best description and methods of the topic of Jhana but even better meditation techniques to achieve Jhana. Link below. Hope this helps.

http://www.bookdepository.com/Mindfulness-Bliss-Beyond-Ajahn-Brahm/9780861712755

Metta

Answer (score 2):

I found the following to be very useful:

**Books**

1. [Focused and Fearless: A Meditator's Guide to States of Deep Joy, Calm, and Clarity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0861715608)

Shaila Catherine writes with a precision and clarity that is missing from most texts on the subject. Great meditation manual as well as guide to the Jhanas. Shaila and Ayya Khema mentioned below seem to write from deep personal experience and this is backed up by their personal histories of practice.

2. [Who Is My Self?: A Guide to Buddhist Meditation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0861711270)

Ayya Khema combines clear and concise instructions that are, for the most part, are a commentary on sections of the Potthapada Sutta that expound on the Jhanas.

**Articles**

1. [A General, All Purpose Jhana Thread](http://www.dharmaoverground.org/discussion/-/message_boards/message/1191517)
2. [Jhana Not by the Numbers by Thanissaro Bhikkhu](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/jhananumbers.html)
3. [THE JHANAS IN THERAVADAN BUDDHIST MEDITATION by LEIGH BRASINGTON](http://www.angelfire.com/electronic/awakening101/janas.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the book [*"Practicing The Jhanas"*](http://www.shambhala.com/practicing-the-jhanas.html) by Tina Rasmussen and Stephen Snyder.

They were both students of Pa Auk Sayadaw and undertook a Samatha Meditation Course under his guidance. Here they achieved the 4 material jhanas and the 4 immaterial jhanas.

The book is streamlined and direct. Not much beating around the bush. They often refer to their own practice and how they trained under Pa Auk Sayadaw. This functions well.

They give lots of useful information and guidance regarding the practice of the Jhanas. I have taken a screenshot of the *table of contents* so you can see what the book contains.

[image]